Redirect to WooCommerce Checkout Page for Custom Rented Room payment
I've made a product data-type for renting rooms (via a custom plug-in called rent_room). I've also created a product page via a copy of WooCommerce's content-single-product.php kept inside my theme's WooCommerce folder. This page uses a php file called "booked-dates" which displays a DatePicker calendar with all the unavailable dates locked from selection; you can only select available dates. As you select the available dates you want, a line on the page "Total Cost" will update with the sum cost of each day you select. (So if the cost per-night for a room is $15 and you select 3 days, the total cost is $45). The days you select are also kept inside a list called 'selected_dates'.
Once you've selected your dates and understand the total cost, you can select 'Book Now.'
This is the issue: Ideally, when they select "Book Now," they should be redirected to the Checkout page and the ONLY THING in their cart should be the "Room Rental". Furthermore, I'm wanting to redirect to the checkout page with the variables "selected_dates" and "total_cost" carried along. The "total_cost" should be inserted as what the customer is paying for those rented days.
I don't know how to do this, and stuff I've looked up doesn't seem to match with what I'm trying to do.
If you need more information or examples of the code, please let me know!
Edit:
Thanks to Devlin for requesting the code, somehow I blanked on that lmao.
So, for the custom-datepicker.js file which handles displaying the calendar and user input, it's first enqueued via the following code:
function enqueue_custom_datepicker() {
    if (is_product()) {
        global $post;
        $product_id = $post->ID;
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

        if ($product) {
            $cost_per_night = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_wcrr_cost_per_night', true);

            // Debug output
            error_log('Enqueuing custom datepicker script.');

            wp_enqueue_script(
                'custom-datepicker',
                get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom-datepicker.js?v=' . time(),
                array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-datepicker'),
                null,
                true
            );

            wp_localize_script(
                'custom-datepicker',
                'roomRentalData',
                array(
                    'costPerNight' => $cost_per_night
                )
            );

                // Localize script with product and checkout data
            wp_localize_script('custom-datepicker', 'customCheckout', array(
                'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
                'product_id' => $product->get_id(),
                'checkout_url' => wc_get_checkout_url(),
            ));
        } else {
            error_log('Product object is not valid.');
        }
    } else {
        error_log('Not on a product page.');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_datepicker');

So the roomRentalData variable is for the costPerNight of the product, and the customCheckout is given the data of the ajax url, the product_id, and the checkout_url.
This is localized in the custom-datepicker.js code, which is used for calculating the total cost and for redirecting to the check-out page.
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Initialize the booking dates.
    var selected_dates = []; 
    var totalCost = 0; 

    // Initialize the datepicker
    $('.room-calendar').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var dateString = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
            // Check if the date is unavailable
            if (unavailableDates.indexOf(dateString) !== -1) {
                return [false, 'unavailable-date', 'Unavailable'];
            } else {
                // Check if the date is selected
                if (selected_dates.indexOf(dateString) !== -1) {
                    return [true, 'selected-date', 'Selected'];
                } else {
                    return [true, '', 'Available'];
                }
            }
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
            var formattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', dateText));
            var index = selected_dates.indexOf(formattedDate);

            // Toggle the date in the array
            if (index === -1) {
                selected_dates.push(formattedDate);
            } else {
                selected_dates.splice(index, 1);
            }

            // Refresh the datepicker to update the UI
            $(this).datepicker('refresh');

            // Debugging: Log the selected dates
            console.log('Selected dates:', selected_dates);

            updateTotalCost();
        }
    });

    // Function to update total cost based on selected dates
    function updateTotalCost() {
        totalCost = selected_dates.length * roomRentalData.costPerNight;
        $('.total-cost').text('Total Cost: $' + totalCost);
        console.log('Total Cost:', totalCost); 
    }

    // Add CSS for the selected dates
    $('<style>')
        .prop('type', 'text/css')
        .html(`
            .ui-datepicker-calendar td.selected-date {
                border: 2px solid green; /* Green border for selected dates */
            }
        `)
        .appendTo('head');


    // Handle the "Proceed to Checkout" button click
    $('#custom-checkout-button').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: customCheckout.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'wcrr_process_booking',
                product_id: customCheckout.product_id,
                selected_dates: selected_dates,
                total_cost: totalCost
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    // Redirect to the WooCommerce checkout page
                    window.location.href = customCheckout.checkout_url;
                } else {
                    console.error('Failed to add to cart');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});

(Note: for convenience, I also paired with the calendar code the AJAX code I thought would work for sending the information over to the checkout page once the user selects "Book now".)
Then in the functions.php file of my theme folder, I'm trying to get the data into the correct session (note that this part of the code I'm the most iffy on; mostly implemented it from stuff seen online, so I'm not 100% on what's going on here, could be the problem):
function wcrr_process_booking() {
    $product_id = isset($_POST['product_id']) ? intval($_POST['product_id']) : 0;
    $selected_dates = isset($_POST['selected_dates']) ? array_map('sanitize_text_field', $_POST['selected_dates']) : [];
    $total_cost = isset($_POST['total_cost']) ? floatval($_POST['total_cost']) : 0;

    if ($product_id && $selected_dates && $total_cost) {
        // Store the custom data in the WooCommerce session
        WC()->session->set('selected_dates', $selected_dates);
        WC()->session->set('total_cost', $total_cost);

        wp_send_json_success();
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error('Invalid data');
    }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_wcrr_process_booking', 'wcrr_process_booking');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wcrr_process_booking', 'wcrr_process_booking');

function wcrr_display_checkout_custom_data() {
    $selected_dates = WC()->session->get('selected_dates');
    $total_cost = WC()->session->get('total_cost');

    if ($selected_dates && $total_cost) {
        echo '<h3>Your Booking Details</h3>';
        echo '<p><strong>Selected Dates:</strong> ' . implode(', ', $selected_dates) . '</p>';
        echo '<p><strong>Total Cost:</strong> ' . wc_price($total_cost) . '</p>';

        // Update the order total with the custom total cost
        WC()->cart->set_total($total_cost);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'wcrr_display_checkout_custom_data');


No, not exactly. I'm asking for how to redirect to the checkout page directly from the product page. I was asked to provide the code I'd originally been using to try and implement this, and that's what you're seeing. (I do ask for input on how to also have two variables carried over and implemented in the check-out page)

So I"m seeing under settings > product the following two options: [] Redirect to the cart page after successful addition, and [x] Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives. Are you referring to the first, to both? And with the wc_get_cart_url();, I'm trying to redirect to the page with my total_cost and selected_dates variables, how are those getting over with just a php redirect in functions.php?
